# Styling :active state on a link

Tags: css

I'm just trying to create a simple menu. So when you click a link, it directs you to another page and shows you that you selected that link by changing colour.

The problem I have is when I click a link within the list, the page loads and for some reason the list elements all enter the `a:visited` field. Setting them to red. I have the [JSFIDDLE Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sR3Ub/2/). I know its simple but it's getting on my nerves.

CSS Code:

```
ul.nav_style{list-style: none;}

ul.nav_style li {padding-left: 1em; text-indent: -.7em;}

ul.nav_style li:before {
    content: "•  ";
    color: #C0C0C0; /* or whatever color you prefer */
}

ul.nav_style li a:link { color: #C0C0C0; text-decoration: none;}
ul.nav_style li a:visited { color: #FF0000; text-decoration: none;}
ul.nav_style li a:hover { color: #58595B; text-decoration: none;}
ul.nav_style li a:active { color: #E6BD13; text-decoration: none;}​
```

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="nav_style">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: They're all the same link. The visited state is determined by where the link points to.

Comment: Say they were going to different pages though

Comment: Even if they're going to different pages, if you've visited those pages, the browser will remember that. Clear your history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I've decided to just use PHP to generate my lists using arrays and an if statement to give the current page its css class.

PHP CODE:

```
if($title == "Enter"){

              $enterArrayPages = array("competition.php","full_detail.php", "judges.php", "get_involved.php", "employers.php");
              $enterArrayText = array("The Competition","Full Detail","The Judges","Get Involved", "Employers");

              echo '<ul class="nav_style">';
              for($i=0; $i<sizeof($enterArrayPages); $i++){

                if($proper_title == $enterArrayText[$i]){
                  echo '<li><a class="linkChange" href="'.$enterArrayPages[$i].'">'.$enterArrayText[$i].'</a></li>';
                }
                else{
                  echo '<li><a class="menu_links" href="'.$enterArrayPages[$i].'">'.$enterArrayText[$i].'</a></li>';
                }
              }
              echo '</ul>';
            }
```

So as you can see, the code loops through each of the pages stored in an array and if the title of the page is equal to the one in the array I change its class, making the color of the link different to the others.

Here is the CSS:

```
a.menu_links:link { color: #58595B; text-decoration: none;}
a.menu_links:visited  { color: #58595B; text-decoration: none; }
a.menu_links:active { color: #E6BD13; text-decoration: none; }
a.menu_links:hover  { color: #E6BD13; text-decoration: none; }

.linkChange {
   color: #E6BD13;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

It's really simple, I just had to think of the logic via PHP. I thought that implementing it in pure css would be good enough, but with time ticking, I resorted to PHP.

Here is an image of the code output:

[image: Code Output, You can see how my code, gets the current page and changes the colour of the link, in this scenario with Mentors and What is Service being highlighted.]

Thanks for everyones comments! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is simple: all the links have the same href. Assuming you will change the hrefs, this will not be an issue on your final site. :)

See my fiddle. All I did was to change the hrefs. Does it work as you expect now? http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/sR3Ub/3/

**EDIT:**
Now, if you simply wish to make sure the link looks the same regardless if it's been visited or not, all you have to do is to apply the same styling to the `:link` and `:visited` states, like so:

```
ul.nav_style li a:link,
ul.nav_style li a:visited { color: #C0C0C0; text-decoration: none;}
ul.nav_style li a:hover { color: #58595B; text-decoration: none;}
ul.nav_style li a:active { color: #E6BD13; text-decoration: none;}
```

Now the link should be grey when idle (even if it's been visited), darker grey when you hover over it, and gold when you click it. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/sR3Ub/5/

**EDIT v2**
It seems you are a little bit confused about the states of a link, so here's the low-down:

`:link` is the standard idle link (can also be targeted simply as `a`)
`:hover` is the act of hovering over the element with the cursor.
`:visited` is applied to links which have already been visited.
`:active` is the state when the link is active in the user interface — e.g. when you are hovering over it, and pressing left mouse button (onmousedown), or when using the <kbd>TAB</kbd> to highlight the link. When you release the mouse button (onmouseup) or tab out, it will revert back to it's previous state.

`:active` therefore have nothing to do with determining if it is the active page, it only applies when you hold the mouse button down.

What you are trying to do, is unfortunately not possible with CSS alone. Here is a simple example of how it can be achieved with jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/sR3Ub/6/

Comment: So yeah, that works, but on the site i am developing. I already implement what you have put. I send the user using href's to different pages in the site simple. But the links do not show that they have been visited.

Comment: if you can see in the link, an image showing that when you click a link, the link corresponding to your page doesnt differ from the rest of the other links. [LINK TO IMAGE](http://imgur.com/h1UTV)

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you trying to remove the special styling for a visited link, so they always appear the same regardless if you've visited them or not? Like so? http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/sR3Ub/5/

Comment: So all i want is when you click the link, you go to the page, and the link goes gold, the others grey. So all I'm trying to get to work is the:
ul.nav_style li a:active { color: #E6BD13; text-decoration: none;}​ line to work.

Comment: that isnt working for me though :| its so weird! so when I click Link 1, i want Link 1 to stay gold, the others grey, when I click Link 2, link 2 goes gold, and the others go grey! It's winding me up! Is it working for you?

Comment: Ooooh! Well, that is not possible with CSS only, you will have to use Javascript for that. See my answer with yet another example.

Comment: `:active` can be more accurately described as when you use the `TAB` key on your keyboard to highlight the link.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a reason of security of browsers, http://dbaron.org/mozilla/visited-privacy
Mozilla http://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/ also informed about this. Most of latest browsers has taken this action to protect the users.

Answer (score 0):

you must put target url in href or in data-href or etc,and after click in link and load new page you must check window location and set link color to red:

```
$(function(){
   var url = window.location.href;
   $("ul.nav_style li").each(function(i,e){
      var $this = $(e);
      if ($this.attr("href") == url){
         $this.css("color","red");
      }
   };
});
```

Comment: Where in OP is there an external library. At least I'm assuming that's where `$` is coming from.

Comment: Why people like to introduce js functions where you don't need them? Beyond my understanding.