# How to make active link stay active on current page

Tags: javascript

Can some look at this code I created with dreamweaver and let me know where and what code to keep the rollover image up when on the current page. Here is my code, let me know if you need more..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-    2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src;  x.src=a[i+2];}
}
 //-->
</script>
   </head>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('../images/aboutover.jpg','../images/marketingover.jpg','../images/eventsover.jpg','../images/galleryover.jpg','../images/projectsover.jpg')">

<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div align="center">
      <p><a href="index.html"><img src="../images/Bconceptslogo.jpg" width="298"  height="123" alt="Boston Concepts" /></a><!-- end .header --></p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="menu"><a href="about.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('about','','../images/aboutover.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/imagebabout.jpg" width="167" height="35" /></a><a href="about.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('about','','../images/aboutover.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/about.jpg" alt="about" width="89" height="35" id="about" /></a><a href="marketing.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('marketing','','../images/marketingover.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/marketing.jpg" alt="marketing" width="160" height="35" id="marketing" /></a><a href="events.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('events','','../images/eventsover.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/events.jpg" alt="events" width="136" height="35" id="events" /></a><a href="gallery.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('gallery','','../images/galleryover.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/gallery.jpg" alt="gallery" width="141" height="35" id="gallery" /></a><a href="projects.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('projects','','../images/projectsover.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/projects.jpg" alt="projects" width="101" height="35" id="projects" /></a><img src="../images/imageapro.jpg" width="161" height="35" /></div>
```

Comment: Please format your code and clarify your question!

Comment: Please explain more. "How to make active link stay active" doesn't make much sense. Your code is terribly obfuscated by Dreamweaver.

Comment: The code doesn't help your question at all. If you just want to change link status to make it looks like "active", just use css rule to make all `:active` and `:visited` link in same color and decoration. Refer to question [Styling :active state on a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334457/styling-active-state-on-a-link)